# Clarification regarding behavior of shell script along with pipe

Tags: linux, shell-script

I need to understand the behaviour of the following shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "First more"
more $1

echo "First echo"
echo $1

echo "Second more"
more $1
```

When I run the following command:

```
echo dir1 | bash script.sh
```

I get the following output

```
First more
dir1
First echo

Second more
```

Why does the `echo` and second `more` not get access to content of `$1`?

When I run the following command:

```
echo dir1 | bash script.sh dir2
```

I get the following command

```
First more

dir1

*** dir2: directory ***

First echo
dir2
Second more

*** dir2: directory ***
```

`dir2` gets passed to all the commands, but more just prints `dir1` but considers `dir2` to be a directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're confusing arguments and standard input. Piping data to a program is not equivalent to giving it command line arguments.

In your first case, you are passing no arguments to your script, only feeding it data through its standard input stream. So `$1` is unset for the whole duration of the script.
The first invocation of `more` thus has no parameter, and pages the standard input. This displays what you had piped in there (`dir1`, as text). The subsequent `echo` only prints a new line since it doesn't get anything to print, and the last `more` has nothing left to print either - standard input has been "drained" by the first one.

In the second case, you do pass an argument. So `$1` has the value `dir2` in the script. The same thing happens, except that the first `more` both:

- pages through both standard input
- attempts to page the file `dir2` and errors out since that's a directory

The echo does what is expected given that `$1` contains `dir2`, and the last `more` only errors on `dir2` - it has nothing to read from standard input.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In my case both dir1 and dir2 are directories. Why is the parameter coming from pipe considered a string but the one passed as argument considered as directory and errors out?

Comment: There is no parameter coming from a pipe. The standard input stream **does not** provide parameters. `more` pages through standard input _without_ interpreting that if you give it something on standard input. It doesn't look at `dir1` at all in either case, it just prints it out verbatim.

Comment: Now it is clear! Thank you! So I assume the only way to transfer the data from pipe into the script is to use echo dir1 | xargs bash script.sh.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do exactly. You can use the `read` builtin to process data from standard input or other files too.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is in "**Arguments**" VS "**Standard Input**".

When you run `echo dir1 | bash script.sh`, the `$1` **argument** in your `script.sh` is always empty as no argument is given to it (try adding a `set -x` at the begin and you will see it in the debug output).
The `dir1` which is echoed comes from **standard input** as the `more` command read stdin if no argument is given (remember `$1` is empty).

**How `cmd1 | cmd2` works**

When using pipe :

1. `cmd2` is a subprocess of `cmd1`.
2. the stdin of `cmd2` is *"plugged"* on the stdout of `cmd1`.

As linux stdio lib offered a buffered stream through file descriptor, the stdin content will be consumed (i.e. read only once) ***only when stdin will be opened***.

**Step by step `cmd1 | cmd2` workflow**

Example command :

> `echo dir1 | (echo "a" ; read stdinvalue; echo "$stdinvalue")`

1. `echo dir1 |` : write "`dir1\n`" on stdout of the first command which is not echoed but buffered through stdio and available to subprocess via stdin.
2. `echo "a"` : write "`a\n`" on stdout ; **doesn't read stdin !** so the "`dir1\n`" string is still available
3. `read stdinvalue` : read stdin until EOL (or EOF) and stores the string in a bash variable
4. `echo "$stdinvalue"` : write stdinvalue variable value to stdout